# Why The Value Of K is Not Increasing in this code?

Tags: c

`#include<stdio.h>`

```
int main()

{
int i=-3, j=2, k=0, m;
m = ++i && ++j || ++k;
printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, k, m);
return 0;
}
```

The value of k increases if i am using a || operator but in case of && the value is not increasing what would be the reason  for that , i am very confused.

The out put is -2,3,0,1

Comment: The value of K is not increased because there is no K. Only a k.

Comment: If you used || operator instead of && as you say, then not only k wouldn't increase but neither would j.

Answer (score 4):

You have a test in your code:

```
m = ++i && ++j || ++k;
```

When you use multiple tests like this, you will first evaluate `++i && ++j`. If it's true, you will **never** evaluate the `|| ++k` part (because `m` would be true anyway). This is called [**lazy evaluation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

If `++i && ++j` had been false in your example, `k` would have been increased because the last part of the test would have been evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

It is called lazy evaluation. false && b is always false whatever b might be.

In your case:
`m = ++i && ++j || ++k;` evaluates to `m = true || ++k;` which leads to `++k` not being evaluated because of lazyness.

Comment: Never. Corrected it. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Corrected where ? I still see `m = false || ++k;` in place of `m = true || ++k;` leading to `++k` never being evaluated. I edited your answer to correct it

Answer (score 2):

Because `++k` is not evaluated as `++i && ++j` evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2):

if the operators of “&&”are not zero，it will come true，then the rest part will not be used.
In c,if it is not zero,it is true.

Answer (score 1):

The OR condition is lazily evaluated.

The `++k` is never executed, because the first part of the condition is not true.

Answer (score 1):

expressions after `||` when the values before it evaluate to true will NOT be evaluated.

`(c=10)|| (y=20)`

In this example, `c=10` evaluates to `true`, due to which `y=20` will not be evaluated.